# Custom Beacon Dashboard?

Tags: eddystone, proximityapi

Is there any other way except `Google beacon` dashboard, where I can create a custom dashboard for my beacon device to set a notification message? Please advise.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the "custom dashboard" that is different than what Google is providing?  More details will help provide good answers.

Comment: I don't want to use Google Beacon dashboard to set nearby notifications. I want to develop my own custom backend where I can set nearby notification. I hope it will give you more clear picture.